# Wiki like Django models

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, mediawiki

I am trying to make a wiki like page in Django.

I have two models `Article` and `ArticleRevision`.

If I want to retrieve the most current revision I think I need an `OneToOneField` in `Article` refering to `ArticleRevision`. But if I want to see the revision history of an article I also need a `ForeignKey` from `ArticleRevision` refering to `Article`.

This is probably the right approach but isn't it a bit overkill to have multiple foreign keys? I could do it with only a `ForeignKey(to=Article)` from ArticleRevision and getting the latest revision from `Article` with `articlerevision_set.latest()`. But if I am making a roll-back to an early revision it will cause troubles. Then I could use a `BooleanField` in `ArticleRevision` to tell if it's the most current revision.

Does anyone have any thoughts about this? I really want to do it the best and most efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [django-revisions](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion). It allows you to do just what you need, without reimplementing everything.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @IronMan84 I agree, but I added the link to the package name. The package name itself should remain stable even if the link breaks.

Answer (score 0):

What about a new field in `ArticleRevision` like **created**, something like:

```
class ArticleRevision(models.Model):
    # Your fields
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_(u'Creation Date'))
```

`auto_now_add=True` <-- This means the field will be autogenerated when an object is created

---

then you can add a new method in your **Article** model like this:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    # Your fields...
    # I will assume you have a foreign key from ArticleReview to Article

    def get_latest_revision(self):
        if self.articlerevision_set.count() > 0:  # If there is revision
            last_revision = self.articlerevision_set.order_by('-created')[0]
            return last_revision
        else:
            return None
```

### Remember: To do this you need a `ForeignKey` **from** `ArticleRevision` **to** `Article`